# when posting data to parse.com using obj c i am getting response as code = 107 error = "invalid json: "

Tags: objective-c, json, curl, parse-platform, nsmutableurlrequest

When I try to post an url through NsMutableUrlRequest to Parse.com I am getting the response as 
  code = 107;
  error = "invalid json: ";

The Function is written in javaScript

But when i post from curl i am getting the exact output.

```
curl -X POST \

  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: appID" \

  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: restAPiKEy" \

  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \

  -d '{}' \
```

https://api.parse.com/1/functions/hello

But in objective c i get the error 
Here is my code

```
 NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.parse.com/1/functions/hello"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";


    NSString * params = @"----the app id---=X-Parse-Application-Id&-----the rest api key=X-Parse-REST-API-Key";


    NSData *data = [params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [request setValue:@"APPID" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-Application-Id"];
    [request setValue:@"REST API KEY" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-REST-API-Key"];
    [request addValue:@"8bit" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Transfer-Encoding"];
    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[data length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:data];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // Peform the request
        NSURLResponse *response;
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSData *receivedData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                                     returningResponse:&response
                                                                 error:&error];
        NSDictionary *dictOfNews  = [NSJSONSerialization
                                     JSONObjectWithData:receivedData //1
                                     options:kNilOptions
                                     error:&error];

        NSLog(@"dict of the news: %@", dictOfNews);


        if (error) {
            // Deal with your error
            if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
                NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
                NSLog(@"HTTP Error: %ld %@", (long)httpResponse.statusCode, error);
                return;
            }
            NSLog(@"Error %@", error);

        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"SUCCESS GRAND SUCCESS");
        }

    });
```

Please tell me, where I am  going wrong. Thanks in advance

Comment: Just curious why you're doing this the hard way, there's a native Objective-C API that wraps the REST calls for you https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide

Comment: @TimothyWalters i am saving and fetching objects using the url u have mentioned but this is cloud code (https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide) written in javascript and to fetch the data is there any other way to fetch "https://api.parse.com/1/functions/hello"  in Xcode?

Comment: `[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"hello" withParameters@{} block:...]` https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#cloudfunctions/iOS

Comment: @TimothyWalters Thank you very much. This works and very simple..